# Sql query too slow - looking for alternative way to write it

Tags: mysql, performance

I have this mysql query that does what it needs to but it takes a really long time to load the content where as my other queries run perfectly fine and quick. Is there a better way to do it? I just want it to load faster. Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT( # Without this I get too many results
        CONCAT_WS(' ', 
            MONTHNAME(a.DateTimeViewed), 
            YEAR(a.DateTimeViewed)
        )
    ) AS ViewedDate, # Displays as "January 2017" (example)
    (
        SELECT COUNT(b.ViewID) 
        FROM views b 
        WHERE 
            MONTH(b.DateTimeViewed) = MONTH(a.DateTimeViewed) AND 
            YEAR(b.DateTimeViewed) = YEAR(a.DateTimeViewed)
    ) as TotalViews 
FROM views a 
    WHERE a.DateTimeViewed >= date_sub(now(), interval 6 month) 
    ORDER BY YEAR(a.DateTimeViewed) ASC, MONTH(a.DateTimeViewed) ASC
```

Comment: I'd suggest, initially, a Group By rather than this weird subquery thing you have going on.

Comment: The results are the latest 6 months with a count of how many page views I have had in each month.

Comment: You do a `count(v.ViewID)` for every row. That doesn't make much sense to include in every row if you ask me (and it also makes things slower than they should).

Comment: Please add the [query execution plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) for your query as well when asking about query performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working too hard.

```
SELECT  CONCAT_WS(' ', MONTHNAME(a.DateTimeViewed), YEAR(a.DateTimeViewed)
                 ) AS ViewedDate,
        COUNT(*) as TotalViews
    FROM  views a
    WHERE  a.DateTimeViewed >= date_sub(now(), interval 6 month)
    ORDER BY  YEAR(a.DateTimeViewed) ASC, MONTH(a.DateTimeViewed) ASC
```

Since you are backing up 6 months from this instant, you are getting the count for only part of the first month.  Perhaps you want to change one line:

```
WHERE a.DateTimeViewed >= CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH, 7), '-01')
```

`COUNT(*)` is the usual way to count rows.  `COUNT(x)` does the same, but adds on the effort to filter out rows with `x IS NULL`.